# Parse.com Getting Query and Converting It into String Java

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, object-to-string

what I'm trying to do is querying a class and getting some strings.
But the below code returns something like ;

```
com.parse.ParseObject@b4209180
```

and I couldn't get it to normal string value.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("question");
//query.whereKeyExists:@"objectId"
query.whereExists("questionTopic");

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> topics, ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e==null){


                textview.setText(topics.toString());

            }


        }else{
             Log.d("notretreive", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }


    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

"topics" in your code is a list of question objects. You need to get the topic from that object. This should get you on the way:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("question");
query.whereExists("questionTopic");

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> questions, ParseException e) {
        // The query returns a list of objects from the "questions" class
        if(e==null){
          for (ParseObject question : questions) {
            // Get the questionTopic value from the question object
            Log.d("question", "Topic: " + question.getString("questionTopic");
          }       
        } else {
             Log.d("notretreive", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

from the [API](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html) I can see that the class `ParseObject` Inherits `toString()` from Object class.

That means unless there is implementation of custom toString() it will return the human-readable description of this object.

check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html?is-external=true#toString%28%29) for the toString() being called in your case

**EDIT:**

First of all you are trying to call toString() on List object by

```
topics.toString()
```

you will have to iterate over that List like

```
for(ParseObject parseObj : topics){
//do something with parseObj like
parseObj.get(<provide_key_here>);
//print to check the value
System.out.println(parseObj.get(<provide_key_here>));
//where key is generally attribute name
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much, but I couldn't understand the usage. If you can simply explain it I would be really thankful.

Comment: check my Edit, also refer http://androidbook.com/item/4458 and also learn Core Java Fundamentals, it will help you resolve such issues faster

Comment: I did everything you said. But the result is same :(
and system.out.println doesn't returns anything. so I'm trying it with settext() .

Comment: `question` is the class name? in `ParseQuery.getQuery("question");`??\

Answer (score 0):

I can see this is about two years old. But I am currently having the same issue. SO here is what I did.

You can't just call setText.toString because "topics" is returning as a Parse Object. You need to run a for loop to run through each topics object and get the text from that object, store it in a string and THEN you can set text to string. Here is what I did.

```
final List questions = new ArrayList<String>();

final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("MasterQuestionList");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(List<ParseObject> Question, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      if (Question.size() > 0) {

        for (ParseObject user : Question) {

         String tFile = (String) user.get("Question");
          questions.add(tFile);

        }

        TextView a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sentence);
        a.setText(String.valueOf(questions));
```

I created a list, and added all text values to that list.

Hope this helps anyone running into a similar issue.

Comment: @clearlight, don't touch my comment. I can see from your profile that you raked in a gold badge by editing *500 or so posts. All you did was change my wording and formatted the post a bit. You offered no additional insight other than to get additional points for yourself. I rolled this back. Hope you see it. ~cheers

Comment: Your post was on a review queue for first post of new user. The goal there is to improve answers by editing, commenting, voting, flagging... I saw idiosyncratic formatting, and more intro than needed and trailing sentences that could be succinct and do better above the code. As for the points/badge accusation - you're confused... I *already have* the badge. You can only get one for editing posts. I do it to improve & clean up posts and I've helped a lot of users. It's weird because there are some red flags in what you've said & done that make you sound like you're not new here but only 1 rep